I’m 13 and I’m interested in Judaism. (Reform)
My name is Charlie, and for a long time, since sixth grade, I’ve been heavily interested in Judaism. I’m not looking to convert just yet. I wanna wait till I’m a full adult. But I have some questions and fears.
I have extremely unsupportive parents. I wanted to celebrate Yom Kippur, but I can’t go to a synagogue. I’m also not good at cooking, and I don't think my mom wants me celebrating Hanukkah either because even though she said she would buy me a menorah, she keeps talking about Christmas around me to mock me. It hurts a lot. :( I feel so hopeless, and I have no support groups or Jewish friends to help me. I feel so invalid and fake, and it hurts so much.
How can a person in my situation learn and practice more Judaism?

Learn as much as you can on your own, and when you become an adult you can make your own decisions.  You have your whole life ahead of you!

Not sure if your asking a question?

Try to make a Jewish friend who knows and practices Judaism.

Try to find meaning within the context of your own religion. Don't antagonize your mother.

Learn about the 7 laws of Noach which were given to all non-Jews, that is what God expects from you (start here: https://www.chabad.org/search/keyword_cdo/kid/2123/jewish/Noahide-Laws-The-Seven.htm)

Many people have difficulty hearing that their children are interested in converting to other religions. Many of the world's religions have a rich history and culture, and to practitioners deciding to converting away seems like spitting on that rich history and culture. It sounds like your mother is not too pleased in your wanting to convert, and it's quite understandable. Try to understand your mother.

I recommend that as long as you live by your parents, you should respect their religion, downplay your interest in Judaism (or even not bring it up at all), and meanwhile read up on Judaism and Noahidism on your own, as a kind of hobby, to see whether you'd really be up for it once you've come of age and are out of the house.

Take heart; our forefather Avraham also grew up in a family that was, shall we say, less than supportive of his attempts to discover G-d (they had him thrown in jail and threatened with execution). Aside from all of the good advice in the other comments, pray to G-d that He lead you in the right path, and may He indeed do so.

Most rabbis will not convert a minor, especially without parental approval or permission. Use these years to privately learn anything you can about our beautiful faith. Here’s a good website to start you off: My Jewish Learning.
There are some Reform and Conservative synagogues that livestream their services. Some of these livestreams are available to the public online; others are private and require you to contact the rabbi to gain access. Just Google “synagogue livestream”.
Opening a line of communication with your local rabbi would be a good idea. Be sure to explain your situation and desire to learn. Though you can’t convert right now, perhaps the rabbi would be able to send you some helpful resources to stimulate your growth in the meantime.
Familiarize yourself with the Seven Laws of Noah. You don’t have to be Jewish to worship and follow the Creator.
Finally, the community here on Mi Yodeya is ready to answer any questions you may have. Be sure to utilize the search function to ensure there is not already an existing question.
Good luck in your journey, and may God always guide you throughout your life!

I'm not so sure that MJL is a good website for the purpose, because a lot of the information there won't necessarily be a good preparation for an Orthodox conversion, which is the only kind that will be accepted by all. Better sites might be chabad.org or aish.com.

@Meir OP was pretty clear from the title they are not interested in an Orthodox conversion. In any case, MJL always presents the traditional approach in every article. Let OP make their own decision as they develop and learn more about Judaism. Chabad and Aish also are extremely biased even from an Orthodox perspective. They just have opinions that line up more with what you believe, which is why you would naturally suggest them.
